# How can i communicate between servlets on same ssl port

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a spring boot application and a traditional javax web servlet running on the same ssl port on an application server.

I want to make a https request to the webservlet from the spring boot app.

Is it possible to communicate between these applications without using SSL? Or, can i reuse the client cert from the client who hit the spring boot app, and pass SSL easily that way?

It seems strange to me that the browser can hop around between the apps easily but the apps cannot communicate directly without proper cert handling.

Answer (score 1):

From what I know of sockets, I don't think this model works. Two applications can't listen to the same port AFAIK.

Comment: i believe they can when they're installed on the same app server, e.g. an external tomcat server or websphere

Comment: Ok.. I usually package the web server in spring boot. So you would need to configure your app server to listen for normal http traffic and route appropriately.